# extracting all the urls from a website using urlextract

Tags: python-3.x

So I came across this package called as urlextract. I wanted to extract all the url's from a website but something seems to be wrong with this.

I tried to search for the error on the but couldn't find anything with this. Would be a great help if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong here

```
from urlextract import URLExtract as extract
blogs = extract.find_urls("www.google.com")


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-b9c0f138f47d> in <module>
----> 1 blogs = extract.find_urls("www.google.com")

TypeError: find_urls() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `find_urls()` is not a `classmethod` of class `URLExtract`, which means in function `find_urls(self,text,*args)` at least two args are needed. 
However, when `URLExtract.find_urls(var)`, i.e. `extract.find_urls(var)` in your code, is executed, only `self` is given, therefore you are given `TypeError` exception account of `"missing argument"`. Therefore, use:

```
from urlextract import URLExtract as extract
extractor = extract()
blogs = extractor.find_urls("www.google.com")
```